# Mingw-64 will not compile openCV code after building and installing

Tags: c++, opencv, command-line, mingw-w64

I built and installed openCV using Cmake and mingw32-make. Afterwards I copied the produced "opencv2" source folder to the "include" folder of my installed mingw-64 compiler. I then copied the produced files from "lib" and "bin" to the corresponding folders of my installed compiler. I finally tried to compiler the following example code to ensure proper installation:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;// new blank image
    image = cv::imread("test.png", 0);// read the file
    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );// show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0);// wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile the code with the following command line command:

```
g++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.cpp
```

Which produced the following error:

```
helloWorld.cpp: In function 'int main()':
helloWorld.cpp:10:36: error: 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' was not declared in this scope
     namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// create a window for display.
```

I suspect I did not properly install openCV, but when I search tutorials online for solving this issue it only is with respect to using codeblocks with mingw. I only wish to use mingw, not codeblocks.

Are there linker options that I am missing? Did I put the ".dll"s and ".dll.a"s in the wrong location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV was indeed installed correctly, the problem was that CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE is a constant used by the C implementation of openCV. When swapped with WINDOW_AUTOSIZE, the code then notified me that I did not link the proper libraries. For openCV 4.2.0, I needed to append "420" to the end of the needed libraries (for example: "-lopencv_core420").

The command line arguments to compile after these changes were made is:

```
g++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.cpp -lopencv_core420 -lopencv_highgui420 -lopencv_imgcodecs420
```